# Jupyter won't connect to a kernel

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook, django-extensions

I'm using django-extensions and I ran `shell_plus --kernel` and it output:

`To connect another client to this kernel, use:
    --existing kernel-6690.json`

Then I tried connecting with Jupyter:

`$  jupyter notebook --existing=kernel-6690.json
[W 10:44:59.290 NotebookApp] Unrecognized alias: '--existing=kernel-6690.json', it will probably have no effect.
...`

Why doesn't Jupyter connect to the kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reviewing https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/4066, it appears that the notebook is not able to connect to kernels. In other words for all the talk about how Jupyter notebook is separated into a kernel and frontend it's actually not and this information is not written in any documentation I could find.

Jupyter notebook does not support connecting to an existing kernel. `shell_plus --notebook` does close enough to what I want.

Comment: very major omission in not mentioning this at all, IMO